# kubernetes upgrade from 1.9.0 to 1.10 FATAL: could not decode configuration: unable to decode config from bytes

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to upgrade my 1.9.0 cluster to 1.10. kubeadm upgrade plan command giving below error message. How to resolve this error message

```
 kubeadm upgrade plan
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/config] FATAL: could not decode configuration: unable to decode config from bytes: v1alpha1.MasterConfiguration: KubeProxy: v1alpha1.KubeProxy: Config: v1alpha1.KubeProxyConfiguration: FeatureGates: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|reGates":"","healthz|..., bigger context ...|24h0m0s"},"enableProfiling":false,"featureGates":"","healthzBindAddress":"0.0.0.0:10256","hostnameOv|...
```

**YAML config file output:**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MasterConfiguration: |
    api:
      advertiseAddress: 192.168.16.211
      bindPort: 6443
    authorizationModes:
    - Node
    - RBAC
    certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    cloudProvider: ""
    etcd:
      caFile: ""
      certFile: ""
      dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
      endpoints: null
      image: ""
      keyFile: ""
    imageRepository: gcr.io/google_containers
    kubeProxy:
      config:
        bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
        clientConnection:
          acceptContentTypes: ""
          burst: 10
          contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
          kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf
          qps: 5
        clusterCIDR: 10.244.0.0/16
        configSyncPeriod: 15m0s
        conntrack:
          max: null
          maxPerCore: 32768
          min: 131072
          tcpCloseWaitTimeout: 1h0m0s
          tcpEstablishedTimeout: 24h0m0s
        enableProfiling: false
        featureGates: ""
        healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10256
        hostnameOverride: ""
        iptables:
          masqueradeAll: false
          masqueradeBit: 14
          minSyncPeriod: 0s
          syncPeriod: 30s
        ipvs:
          minSyncPeriod: 0s
          scheduler: ""
          syncPeriod: 30s
        metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249
        mode: ""
        oomScoreAdj: -999
        portRange: ""
        resourceContainer: /kube-proxy
        udpTimeoutMilliseconds: 250ms
    kubeletConfiguration: {}
    kubernetesVersion: v1.9.0
    networking:
      dnsDomain: cluster.local
      podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
      serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
    nodeName: k8sm-01
    token: ""
    tokenTTL: 24h0m0s
    unifiedControlPlaneImage: ""
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-10-06T20:44:05Z
  name: kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "2462269"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config
  uid: 1818b79c-aad7-11e7-9ef5-525400ada096
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is followed by [kubernetes issue 61764](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61764), which mentions the [**Before upgrading** section](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.10.md#before-upgrading):

> `kube-proxy`: feature gates are now specified as a map when provided via a JSON or YAML `KubeProxyConfiguration`, rather than as a string of key-value pairs.
>   For example:
>
> `KubeProxyConfiguration` Before:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>  kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
>  **featureGates: "SupportIPVSProxyMode=true"**
> ```
>
> `KubeProxyConfiguration` After:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>  kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
>  **featureGates:**
>  **  SupportIPVSProxyMode: true**
> ```

And:

> if `featureGates: ""`, replace with with `featureGates: {}`

Actually, the [OP sfgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344669/sfgroups) ads [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602742/kubernetes-upgrade-from-1-9-0-to-1-10-fatal-could-not-decode-configuration-una/49603827#comment86246695_49603827):

> changed config like this: `featureGates: {""}`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. changed config like this: `featureGates: {""}`

Comment: @sfgroups Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.